# Jquery:-BxSlider not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, bxslider

I am using BXslider via jquery..The problem I am facing is that while sliding,the slider is going past the last element that is,it is not stopping when the last element has come..This is the Jquery code I am using:-

```
$('.header_sub_nav').bxSlider({
  //mode: 'horizontal',
  controls: false,
  infiniteLoop: false,
  pager: false,
  maxSlides: 2,
  onSliderLoad: function() {
    $('.header_subnav .bx-viewport')
      .css({
        'background': 'transparent',
        'border': 'none',
        'box-shadow': 'none',
        'padding': '0 10% 0 0',
        'left': '0'
      });    
  }    
});
```

I have gone through various links and tried code to stop this..its not working out for me.

The below is my Plunker..But am not able to generate the above condition whic is taking place in my local
**[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/pXMnM09ZubyAC9Tq4b41?p=preview)**

Is there any option which I am missing out.

Can someone please help me out..Thanks for the help

Comment: create a jsfiddle.net example for us to see.

Comment: @BenG I have created the fiddle please check it out.Thanks